# How can I access and count a value of an attribute of Json file in Python?

Tags: python, json, attributes, malware

I have this json file. It's a report of threat intelligence platform.

```
{
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "authentihash": "a077f952798eb3bc0730c7c4774da7636326cf4b524ed6571b7eaf3d43f0bd9b",
            "creation_date": 1387937380,
            "crowdsourced_yara_results": [
                {
                    "author": "Florian Roth",
                    "description": "Malware InstallRex / AntiFW",
                    "rule_name": "PUP_InstallRex_AntiFWb",
                    "ruleset_id": "000ca30c43",
                    "ruleset_name": "crime_antifw_installrex",
                    "source": "https://github.com/Neo23x0/signature-base"
                }
            ],
            "first_submission_date": 1389124248,
            "last_analysis_date": 1603898773,
            "last_analysis_results": {
                "ALYac": {
                    "category": "undetected",
                    "engine_name": "ALYac",
                    "engine_update": "20201028",
                    "engine_version": "1.1.1.5",
                    "method": "blacklist",
                    "result": null
                },
                "APEX": {
                    "category": "undetected",
                    "engine_name": "APEX",
                    "engine_update": "20201028",
                    "engine_version": "6.90",
                    "method": "blacklist",
                    "result": null
                },
                "AVG": {
                    "category": "malicious",
                    "engine_name": "AVG",
                    "engine_update": "20201028",
                    "engine_version": "18.4.3895.0",
                    "method": "blacklist",
                    "result": "FileRepMetagen [Malware]"
                },
```

I would count how many antimalware detected the malware as "maliciuous". So
i can access and print the whole list of "last_analysis_results", but i can't access to "category" of each antimalware.
I try with:

```
for elem in data['data']['attributes']['last_analysis_results']:
```

but then? thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.values()` to get the dictionary values. Then you can access the `category` element of each dictionary.

```
sum(r['category'] == 'malicious' for r in data['data']['attributes']['last_analysis_results'].values())
```

Booleans are treated as 1 and 0 when used arithmetically, so summing the comparisons counts the number of times it's true.

Comment: you probably mean sum instead of count?

Comment: yes i mean sum, sorry. I solved with Barmar answer. thank you

Comment: @daisy The comment was intended for me, I originally wrote `count` in the answer.

Comment: @Barmar okay :) . Might ask I you another thing? i have an attribute in json that i would print, but not for all the element it's present. so when the script doesn't find it, the console print 'KeyError: 'creation_date''. How can i solve this with exception? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can either `try/except` to catch the error, use `if 'creation_date' in xxx:`, or use `xxx.get('creation_date', default_date)`